# How can I check if there is a Windows UAC Elevation Administrator Prompt awaiting for confirmation?

Tags: windows, shell, process, uac

I would like to programmatically know if my Windows 7 system is **stopped in the UAC elevation prompt**, awaiting for the user to press "Yes".

Is there any **running process** that appears only in this case and disappear when the user accepts elevation? That would be a good solution, because I could check it via `tasklist`.

I have checked (during UAC prompt stopped and waiting) for these **patterns**:

- uac
- admin
- prompt
- elev
- req
- cacl
- cscript

...with no luck (all of them case insensitive).

Comment: What's provoking the question (why do you need to know)?

Comment: The main reason is for `learning`, but it could be useful in some cases. For example, sometimes, don't know why, the UAC process get `backgrounded`, and gets unnoticed for the user when installing some programs. Another reason: some installer do invoke UAC after a while, not in the beginning; if you need to leave the computer alone, it could be worthful to have `some way to alert` (maybe by playing some music or so). But I must admit: this time I wanna solve this for `programmatical purposes`. See next comment, @Bill_Stewart.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart: Trying to resume: I am trying to mod SUDO for CygWin ( https://github.com/nu774/sudo-for-cygwin ) to request for UAC before `sudoserver.py` starts. So, the `sudo` python process that communicates with sudoserver.py does not find it running (it is waiting for UAC confirmation before starting) and exits with error. The full explanation is a bit longer, but I am proposing to share the code (mostly scripts) with the forum when finished (it is nearly done, I think).

Answer (score 1):

I have found it via remote SSH:

```
c:\>tasklist | find "consent" -i
consent.exe                   5700 Console                    1    14.784 KB
```

It keeps running while your desktop is on UAC.